# Oracle 12c - other database sessions long running during SQL-LOADER session running

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

When a session is loading the table on a different partition using the `SQLLDR` to spool one flat file , we see other sessions on the same table starts long running and are  failing after a long time with the error

`"ORA-08103: object no longer exists"`

We did some initial check for this.

1. Our table is partitioned and we are using partition key to load from the flat file.
2. Table's Object id is not changing during that period. Only the partition's Id is changing because we are doing a truncate partition before loading.
3. We have no global index on it,all indexes are local.
4. Some flat files are too huge and sometime the AWR report shows complete I/O system consumed.

Comment: No solution, but maybe this gives you a hint: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/422083_1.html It seems like the truncate is the "source of evil"

Comment: Yes, we tested this theory also, but the truncate is on the partition of the table , not the whole table. it causes this issue when truncate is changing the object id ,but it only changes the object id of the partition , other partition is not impacted.